# Dialog with max height and dynamic Content that scrolls + footer css

Tags: css, height, max, scrollable, dynamic-content

I have a **dialog** with **position: absolute** and a **max-height** set. The **max-height** property is **set** from outside **by** a **javscript** framework (jQuery UI Dialog), so I don't have any control over it. Inside I have 2 divs: one that is filled with **dynamic content** and a **static footer**.
I want the **dialog** to grow with it's content **until max-height** is reached and after that my content div should display a **scrollbar**.

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="dialog">
    <div class="content">
        This text doesn't mean much it's just supposed to fill content.<br>
        This text doesn't mean much it's just supposed to fill content.
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="copyright">
        © copyright 2015 by some chilled dude
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css like this:

```
.dialog {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    max-height: 300px;
    border: solid black 1px;
}

.content {
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

The problem is, the content will always blowout its surrounding dialog and push down the footer.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/isaraystanz/eq645d49/)

If I set the the height of the dialog div everything is fine.

[example2](http://jsfiddle.net/isaraystanz/cm34q5j8/)

I can calculate the height with javascript and set it on my dialog ([example3](http://jsfiddle.net/isaraystanz/z5jqw0ap/)), but I would like to do this using only css. Is that possible ?

Comment: this may be a daft question, but if the max-height of your dialogue is 300px and the max-height of your content is 100% - 20px, couldn't you just set the max-height of content to 280px to get your desired result? http://jsfiddle.net/cm34q5j8/3/

Comment: agreed @Pete and obviously calc() doesn't calc with parent only set to min* or max* values, is there anything to do with both dynamic height of content + footer? since OP emphasised **dynamic** multiple time, anyway flexbox can rescue.

Comment: Ah ok @Pangloss, the dynamic thing can be solved by moving the calc to the height: http://jsfiddle.net/cm34q5j8/6/ (if you change the height of html frame you will see it works)

Comment: I don't know the value of max-height when the dialog is created, it is set by a framework via javascript so the max-height here was just the example of a dialog instance. Sorry I didn't point this out in my post.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative approach, you could use `flexbox`.

```
.dialog {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    max-height: 300px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}
.content {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6ozon8o/)

Comment: Your example looks really promising. I've tried flex here before with different settings (dialog:flex/coumn, content:grow 1 shrink 0,copyright: shrink 0 grow 0 basis ~20px) but I wasn't successfull so I made this example. I'm trying your solution right now but it seems either jQuery ui or the surrounding css is interfering with the layout.