# set contents div with scrollbar only on it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 5 div's in the project, (header, left dropdown menu, center content div, right menu guide, bottom footer), I need to keep this div in the center, for all content dynamically inserted, does not let create scrollbar in the entire project, only the content div, may contain scroll bar ..
Can someone explain to me how I can do this, please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHT5t.jpg)

Comment: take a look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993779/dialog-with-max-height-and-dynamic-content-that-scrolls-footer-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a modern approach to make CSS layout check this snippet. It use the new CSS grid layout module that allow yout to make layouts that are content agnostic and not flow-based. Here the [Can i Use Reference](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20grid)

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.AppShell {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  grid-template-rows: 4fr 20fr 4fr;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 10fr 200px;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header"
                       "leftside content rightside"
                       "footer footer footer";
}


.Header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: powderblue;
}


.LeftSide {
  grid-area: leftside;
  background-color: sandybrown;
}


.Content {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: mediumturquoise;
  overflow: auto;
}

.RightSide {
  grid-area: rightside;
  background-color: papayawhip;
}

.Footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<main class="AppShell">
  <section class="Header">Header</section>
  <section class="LeftSide">Left</section>
  <section class="Content"><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ex excepturi veritatis dicta debitis repellendus illo, laboriosam corporis, nostrum ratione, voluptatem, accusantium est optio laborum soluta totam odit facere architecto.</div>
  <div>Debitis a, adipisci tempore error repudiandae labore assumenda natus modi illo alias impedit esse amet beatae culpa enim tenetur maxime ipsa fuga voluptatem nobis sint nulla optio soluta sit ad.</div>
  <div>Voluptatem officia asperiores dolores magnam perferendis praesentium, id, impedit facilis dignissimos enim, pariatur esse. Nam praesentium quam incidunt perspiciatis, consectetur vel, architecto quia reiciendis nobis vitae eligendi dolorum voluptatibus fugit?</div>
  <div>Alias dolor dicta incidunt laboriosam id accusamus nesciunt doloremque harum reprehenderit, in quo corrupti, obcaecati, aliquid pariatur totam ullam quia ab ratione ex nobis ut! Saepe ab eos deleniti adipisci.</div>
  <div>Quaerat, placeat dolorem rem, incidunt illum harum suscipit illo! Tempore hic deleniti perferendis a numquam recusandae minus quibusdam aperiam harum magnam excepturi reprehenderit, cum, voluptatibus similique, voluptatem sit temporibus accusantium!</div>
  <div>Molestiae consequuntur fugit voluptatum quasi illum quam animi quibusdam minima neque culpa, optio recusandae, ipsa est. Iure sunt, porro sequi. Ipsa dolor, obcaecati laborum nulla vitae? Eligendi, magnam labore vitae.</div>
  <div>Cum natus maiores, impedit ipsum expedita quo accusantium, aliquam nulla, ipsa quia eveniet eos ex. Beatae consectetur maiores cumque sapiente facilis, cum impedit quibusdam dicta consequatur odio, officiis temporibus facere.</div>
  <div>Excepturi ipsa eligendi dicta fuga laudantium dolorum cupiditate iste quo neque non maiores molestiae doloremque dignissimos, iure provident culpa cumque praesentium in assumenda beatae possimus vel. Eum quod, libero expedita?</div>
  <div>Mollitia fuga explicabo natus nobis, laborum itaque hic molestias atque, laboriosam, iste eos nemo vel sed asperiores! Neque dolore quo vel maxime exercitationem quod, sint. Similique delectus quo sit! Temporibus?</div>
  <div>Sunt sequi ducimus obcaecati perspiciatis ipsam, provident expedita qui unde nesciunt, est asperiores odio consequatur incidunt tempora adipisci iusto mollitia enim. Iste quaerat non, obcaecati, ea aliquid quasi quidem. Impedit?</div></section>
  <section class="RightSide">Right</section>
  <section class="Footer">Footer</section>
</main>
```

Comment: Set the correct aswer so others can read the solution (or one of them)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `max-height` & `overflow: auto` to the content div in the middle should bring you the expected result.